# What could be wrong with my Xcode 6.0.1 playground?

Tags: xcode6, swift-playground

I'm just trying to create an image object on a playground:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage    

let image = CIImage()
```

And all get is this error:

```
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_l386_PTB, subcode=0x0).
```

If I try to create a CIFilter I get an error as well so I'm assuming it is something to do with CoreImage on playgrounds.

Note I'm using: OSX 10.9.5

Comment: I also had the same problem, it looks that you cant use core image on playground yet

Comment: As a workaround, you can use a regular xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

CoreImage is not available in Playgrounds.